# The Limit of the Minimum of Two Random Variables...

Tags: probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, order-statistics

> I am looking at the following random variable:
>   $$T = \min_n{\{Q_n + X \cdot S_n\}}$$
>
> where $Q_n$ and $S_n$ are exponentially distributed, and $X$ is a constant.
>   I am interested in two things.
>
> 1. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, what does $T$ converge in distribution to? and,
> 2. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, what does $E[T]$ converge to?

I think that

1. It may converge to some type of Shifted Erlangian-2 r.v. and
2. It looks like $E[T] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ w.p. 1.

But, I don't know how to prove (or show) this and I may not even be correct in my conclusions above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this not depend on the parameters of said exponential distributions?